# Clever ways to read a text file into a pandas dataframe with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, indexing

I have a text file that gives me a list of "blobs," each with an index, and then the area of the blobs at each time step that they exist.

I want to get:
a) the duration, in time steps, of each blob 
b) the average area of each blob across all times steps for which it exists

The text file looks like this:

[image: screen shot of text file I want to get into a data frame]

Technically, the duration of each blob is already given in parentheses after the Blob index, but there are 60,000 blobs so I need a way to extract this data and figured if I could get it into a pandas data frame, I could just do a "count" on the areas to get the duration.

However, I am having trouble figuring out the best way to parse the text file into a usable pandas data frame. I think that the Blob X labels need to be an index, somehow, and I'm sure I need to use regex to do that. However, I have never worked with regular expressions and would love some advice.

So far, I have the following (not that impressive, I know):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="\t")
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().str.lower().str.replace(' ', '_')
print(df)
```

But the only "column" that pandas is finding is the very first Blob 1 (1). Any ideas on how to parse the text file to get it into a usable data frame format?

Comment: No images please and try to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293327/use-python-to-split-a-csv-file-with-multiple-headers)

Comment: I'm not sure that a single Pandas DataFrame for the whole thing is really the best data structure.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to this problem would be first to split the rows into blocks of data
using the `"Blob"` word on the first column as separator, and from the second
column extract the `Blob` number as integer. From there, calculate the mean of each block
and place into a new column on the previously created frame. To get the duration of
each `Blob` from the frame use the pandas `split` with the regex `r'\(|\)'`, but this
can also be easily obtained with `len(chunk)` inside the for-loop.

Input file **data.txt**

```
Blob    1   (1)
0       0.00074
Blob    2   (2)
0       0.00065
1       0.00073
Blob    3   (1)
0       0.00095
Blob    4   (1)
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep="\s+", header=None)

dft = df[df[0] == "Blob"].copy()
# place Blob index as integer
dft["Blob"] = dft[1].astype(int)
# discard columns
dft = dft.iloc[:, 3:]

idx = dft.index.tolist()
idx.append(df.shape[0])

# compute the mean of row data chunks
for i in zip(idx, idx[1:]):
    chunk = df.iloc[i[0] + 1:i[1], 1]
    dft.loc[i[0], "Mean"] = chunk.mean()

# get duration already in the frame
dft["Duration"] = df[2].str.split(r'\(|\)', expand=True)[1]

print(dft.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output from **dft**

```
   Blob      Mean Duration
0     1  0.000740        1
1     2  0.000690        2
2     3  0.000950        1
3     4  0.001760        1
4     5  0.001100        1
5     6  0.001389       18
6     7  0.001850        1
```